# Inkscape: design and print a banner with an appropriate resolution

Tags: print-design, inkscape, print-production

I need to print a banner with the size of 3x1m. Does that mean I should design the banner in Inkscape (my prefered vector software) with the canvas size of 3m x 1m also? Or could I design in smaller ratio like 30cm x 10cm?

Actually, I have designed it with the canvas size of 3m x 1m. In order to print it in 3m x 1m, so when I export my design to PNG, should I enter the banner size of 10630px x 3543px?

Thanks.

Comment: PNG? Why PNG ??  
You meant PDF right?

Comment: @Vinny Sorry, I have never printed a banner before. This is the first time. So I must have PDF while printing? Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG is mostly intended for web and small images, icons, etc, while **PDF** is generally the standard for printing. Also, forget about pixels when doing print work. Read [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/56480/exporting-from-indesign-for-print-pdf-jpeg-or-png) for a detailed explanation of how formats work.

This should be discussed with the company going to produce the actual banners, since each printer has different ways of looking at this, depending on their machines, workflow, etc. While most printers will probably prefer to print PDF's, some could require a JPG or TIF or EPS format.

When exporting a **PDF** for print, make sure you include **crop** and **bleed** marks, also something you need to discuss with the printing company.

About the actual size, you should be fine if you already have the canvas set to 3x1 meters, or half-size at 1.5x0.5 meters should also be fine. If the artwork is 100% vectors it should be easy to adjust this later in the process.

Comment: The canvas size of 30cm x 10cm is also okay?

Comment: That's 10 times smaller, so not sure. It could work with a few quick adjustments. Show the PDF to your printer and they will be able to confirm this. If you already have a 3x1 canvas, use it.

Comment: Okay thanks. By the way, I am designing using Inkscape, which all vectors.

Comment: Wait.
"If the artwork is 100% vectors it should be easy to adjust this later in the process.".
Does that mean I can export to different sizes?

Comment: Yes, because vectors can easily be scaled up (from a smaller size to a larger size) without quality loss.

Comment: that's the point of vectors (only the ratio and vomposition matters)you can scale it up and down as much as you want and nothing except the size should change

Comment: Hello, I want to ask again. My canvas size is 30cm x 10cm. I have exported it to PDF with the same size. So how should I do to print the PDF with 3m x 1m?

Comment: Ok. I have never used Inkscape but, can you, or can you not change the canvas size to 3x1m and scale the artwork up 10 times? This is very easy to do in Illlustrator (only takes a minute) so i _assume_ it should also be easy in Inkscape? (in the original question you mentioned the canvas size was 3x1m, now its 30x10cm? :)

Comment: In the export file dialog, you can increase the resolution, which is normally 96dpi as you like, so in your case 960dpi. But I don't print often and would ask the printing service for advice.